# How do I keep header bar to stay when opening external site within webapp?

Tags: ipad, web-applications, jquery-mobile, header, navigation

I am trying to use a web app to access a few key internal sites in the business.
The web app opens full screen and there is no address bar etc. The main page has a header bar with a back and a home button. 
To open the internal links within the webapp the following code has been used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenLink(theLink){
window.location.href = theLink.href;
}
</script>
```

along with the below in the 'a href'

```
onclick="OpenLink(this); return false"
```

The new page opens within the web app with no address bar etc, but how do I keep the web apps header bar with the back and home buttons in it for basic navigation?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use an iFrame for this. 
Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/aziqap/1